# elasticsearch tire gem exact match

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, tire

I'm currently using Tire to access my ES data however I've not been able to get it to do an exact match, for instance

```
User.search :per_page => 10 do 
 query do
    boolean do
       must { match :first_name, 'tom'}
       must { match :last_name, 'smith'}
       end
   end
end
```

However that returns firstnames that are tom, tomas, tommy and tomiena.. when I'd like it to only match tom.

Comment: It depends on used analyzer. Whats your [mapping](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/)?

Answer (score 1):

Try the match_phrase query,

```
User.search :per_page => 10 do 
 query do
    boolean do
       must { match :first_name, 'tom', :type => :phrase}
       must { match :last_name, 'smith', :type => :phrase}
       end
   end
end
```

Comment: I get undefined method `match_phrase` for Tire::Search::Query with this.

Comment: @jeremywoertink Which version of Tire do you use?

Comment: I have version `0.6.1` running.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, can you try match with `:type => phrase` as option. If this works please let me know. I will update the answer accordingly. I just gave the answer based on elasticsearch options. I thought Tire would be using the same option.

Comment: Yup, that did the trick!. The updated answer works fine for me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with a **query_string** query :

```
User.search :per_page => 10 do 
 query do
    boolean do
       must { string 'first_name:tom'}
       must { string 'last_name:smith'}
       end
   end
end
```

If that doesn't work it means that you'd have to check on your analyser.